# Link css on vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have a bit problem to link vue.js and scss.

I have this AppHeader.vue archive:

```
<template>
  <header id="header" class="header">
    <div class="header-container container">
      <nav>
        <a class="btn-icon logo-btn" href="/">
          <img
            class="logo logo-normal"
            src="../assets/logo.svg"
            alt="Logo petinder"
          />
          <img
            class="logo logo-white"
            src="../assets/logo_white.svg"
            alt="Logo petinder"
          />
        </a>

        <ul class="menu-links">
          <li><a href="">Servicios</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Header",
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.header {
  background: $accent;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.aright {
  text-align: right;
}
```

I have another folder where I have four scss archives. One of them, _base.scss, has the css body like this:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;  
    color: $text-color;
    font-family: $font-family-sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    max-width:100%;   
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

ul, li{
    list-style: none; 
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
}

.app-container{
    min-height: calc(100vh - 61px);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; 
    //padding-top: 70px;
}

main{
    height: 100%;
    flex:1;
}
```

The problem is that css body is not working on the AppHeader.vue. When I see it on the webrowser, the body has no width.

How can I link them?

Thanks.

Comment: Your css doesnt have width for body also. max-width isn't exactly width.

Comment: Anyway, I have a list-style: none and is not working.

Comment: Can't you add that css to component's style part?

Comment: I have an AppHeader.vue archive and _base.scss archive. I want to link them

Comment: Have u imported the scss file inside main.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do this is by using this inside the style,

result: `<style src='../style.css' scoped>`

It's more useful because you can use scoped with this method.

Comment: It works! But i have a problem. I transfer the HEADER style on vue.js archive but the website don't have the same dimensions. Am I transfering the css badly? I have and index.html with css and it looks well, but i trasnfer the css on vue.js and it looks bad.

Comment: I don’t fully understand what you mean, could you maybe show an example?

Comment: Also, could you please upvote my answer, that way I get more reputation

Answer (score 0):

best way for the link your css file to the vue component is the import your css to the App Header.vue component, like this

```
<style lang="scss">
    @import "./path/_base.scss"; // please enter your current path
</style>
```

***course sure that used of webpack in your project that help you for modular***